# How to decode protobuf in Postman?

Tags: postman, protocol-buffers

We have two endpoints in the same collection, one GET and one POST, where the POST endpoint request body is dependent on the response body of the GET endpoint. The problem is that the GET endpoint's response body is a huge protobuf message, so it is represented as a base64 string (there are other reasons the message should be serialized too).

Is there a way to decode the protobuf response in the Postman client?

Comment: qquestion is how to convert base64 to normal string ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The GET response body is a base64-encoded string.

Comment: So you just want to decode it from base 64 ?

Comment: No. Decoding it from base64 gives me protobuf-encoded bytes, and I want to get the protobuf message (perhaps as a JSON object)